# Villagers aren't breeding (Realms - 1.15.2)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

They aren't picking up my potatoes, bread and even my carrots. I have a ton of beds, I've even tried trading with them but it wont work, any tips? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/gamerule doMobGriefing false`

This command disables creeper explosions from breaking blocks and prevents villagers from picking up food, among other things. Try
`/gamerule doMobGriefing true`

Comment: Unless it's changed between 1.15.1 and 1.15.2 it should be `/gamerule mobGriefing true`